# Reading csv with variable number of columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a variable number of columns.

Pandas can handle the situation fairly easily with the `name` parameter. This works if the first row of the file is either the same length or shorter of `names`, but fails if it's longer.

### Examples

#### Case 1

First row has the same number of elements as `names`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

file = StringIO(
        '''1, 2, 3,
           1, 2
           1, 2, 3, 4, 
           1, 2, 3,''')

df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['A','B','C'], index_col=False)
df

# Out[0]:
#    A  B    C
# 0  1  2  3.0
# 1  1  2  NaN
# 2  1  2  3.0
# 3  1  2  3.0
```

This **works**.

#### Case 2

First row has less elements than `names`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

file = StringIO(
        '''1, 2,
           1, 2
           1, 2, 3, 4, 
           1, 2, 3,''')

df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['A','B','C'], index_col=False)
df

# Out[0]:
#    A  B    C
# 0  1  2  NaN
# 1  1  2  NaN
# 2  1  2  3.0
# 3  1  2  3.0
```

This **works** too.

#### Case 3

First row has **more** elements than `names`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

file = StringIO(
        '''1, 2, 3, 4,
           1, 2
           1, 2, 3, 4, 
           1, 2, 3,''')

df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['A','B','C'], index_col=False)
df

# Expected output:
#    A  B    C
# 0  1  2  3.0
# 1  1  2  NaN
# 2  1  2  3.0
# 3  1  2  3.0
#
# Instead I get:
# IndexError: list index out of range
```

This **doesn't work!!!**

#### Question

Is there a way to make this script more robust so that it handles also Case 3 without generating an error?
Doesn't this looks a bit like a bug

I'm running pandas version 0.23.4

### EDIT:

#### Case 3b

First row has **more** elements than `names`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

file = StringIO(
        '''1, 2, 3, 4
           1, 2
           1, 2, 3, 4, 
           1, 2, 3,''') # NOTE: No comma after the first "4"!!

df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['A','B','C'], index_col=False)
df

#Out[0]:
#    A  B    C
# 0  1  2  3.0
# 1  1  2  NaN
# 2  1  2  3.0
# 3  1  2  3.0
```

This **works!!!**

What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make use of the `usecols` params, instead of the `names` one. `names` assume that you're listing all the columns' name, whereas `usecols`assume a subample of the columns.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

file = StringIO(
        '''1, 2, 3, 4,
           1, 2
           1, 2, 3, 4, 
           1, 2, 3,''')

df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols =[0,1,2], header = None)
df
0   1   2
0   1   2   3.0
1   1   2   NaN
2   1   2   3.0
3   1   2   3.0
```